# Search function with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, web

I am trying to redirect users to a dedicated search page when they type into the search box and click send from any page on my website. Is it possible to accomplish this with JS:

1. Use ajax request to pull data based on search input
2. Redirect user to dedicated search page
3. Build new search page based on data from ajax request

The issue I am having is that JS needs to be executed on two different pages within the same function, I am not sure how to structure this properly.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) post for how to ask better questions, which will help people give you better answers. In particular, adding the code of what you've already tried will help people understand your problem and it's context better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really easy. Suppose this is your generated HTML

```
<form...>
...
<div class="search">
<input type="text" id="txtSearch" name="search" />
<input type="submit" id="btnSearch" value="Search" />
</div>
...
</form>
...
<script>
window.onload = function(){
   function searchRedir(){
      var searchKey = document.getElementById('txtSearch').value;
      window.location = '/<searchPageUrl>?search=' + escape(searchKey);
      return false;
   }
   document.getElementById('txtSearch').onchange =
   document.getElementById('btnSearch').onclick = searchRedir;

}
```

Submit Button btnSearch is added in case user browser doesn't support javascript (or support is turned off). In this case you have to redirect the request to a search page on server side. The code may differ a little depending on server-side technology.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible.

Here's what to google for each of those:

1.- "How to do an ajax request with (Javascript/Any framework you are using)", if you are not using any frameworks I would recommend using [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent) to simplify your requests. But this is not necessary you can do Ajax with normal JavaScript a `GET` request would look like this (credits to [You might not need jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)):

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', '/my/url', true);

request.onload = function() {
  if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
    // Success!
    var resp = this.response;
  } else {
    // We reached our target server, but it returned an error

  }
};

request.onerror = function() {
  // There was a connection error of some sort
};

request.send();
```

2.- "How to redirect a user to an URL using (Javascript/Any framework you are using)" and to concatenate this with 3 "How to set URL parameters with (Javascript/Any framework you are using)"

3.- "How do I access URL parameters with (Javascript/Any framework you are using)"

If you Google those 3 you should be able to do what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting a user to a new page when they start typing seems like confusing behaviour. I suggest that you redirect the user to the your search page when they click on the search box or you can just replace the box with a link. If you need parameters from the requesting page, you can append them to your url like myexamplesite/search?myparam=Thethingineed

Comment: I am only redirecting them after they click enter or search, the issue is timing it properly so the JS to update the page is run on the newly loaded search page rather than the page where the search box is filled

Comment: ah. okay. maybe run a separate script on the search page that fires once the page is done loading? You can always grab the data you need in the url. Depending on JS run and Page loading speeds seems error prone to me.